# RegEx space between [a-z] and [0-9]

Tags: r, regex, gsub

I am almost there, but I'm stuck. I got this:

```
string99 <- c("Foo  /10", "Foo Bar 7 / 0", "FooBar 25 / 5", "I do 156 / ")
#> [1] "Foo /10"     "Foo Bar 7 / 0" "FooBar 25 / 5" "I do 156 / "  
gsub("[^[:alnum:][:space:]]",",",string99)
#> [1] "Foo  ,10"      "Foo Bar 7 , 0" "FooBar 25 , 5" "I do 156 , "
```

but what I would like is to get this,

```
gsub(magic)
#> [1] "Foo, ,10"     "Foo Bar,7 , 0" "FooBar,25 , 5" "I do,156 , "
```

The extra white space± is not too important, as I'm reading with a `read.csv` from here, but that first comma, only when it's before a number is driving me up the wall. So, I need two commas in each string.

Update, Wiktor Stribiżew [linked to some code below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49989148/regex-space-between-a-z-and-0-9?noredirect=1#comment86995200_49989148) that gives this result:

```
gsub("^\\D*?\\K(?=\\d+|/)|[^[:alnum:][:space:]]",",",string99, perl=TRUE)
#> [1] "Foo  ,/10"      "Foo Bar ,7 , 0" "FooBar ,25 , 5" "I do ,156 , "
```

even closer, but there's some forward slash, `/`, happening in `"Foo  ,/10"`, I guess it's about substituting that for a `,`.

Comment: Try [`gsub("^\\D*\\K|[^[:alnum:][:space:]]",",",string99, perl=TRUE)`](https://ideone.com/wTs7P8)

Comment: The line after `gsub(magic)` is my _desired outcome_. I do want two commas in in the last instance, i.e. `"I do,156 , "`. I'm I overlooking some point here?

Comment: `gsub('(?<=[a-z])(?=\\s+\\d)|/', ',', string99, perl = TRUE)` but ^^^ is cooler

Comment: Amazing how you both do this, I did however just release that in the data I have on my machine, that is not the foobar string, it also happens that the first number is missing, i.e. the updated `"Foo  /10"` any way to solve that?

Comment: What is the expected output now?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, thank you for your prompt response. I updated the _desired outcome_ too. Same logic, two commas. Does that make sense?

Comment: Try [`gsub("^\\D*?\\K(?=\\d+|/)|[^[:alnum:][:space:]]",",",string99, perl=TRUE)`](https://ideone.com/bKEyL3). Or `"^[^\\d/]*\\K|[^[:alnum:][:space:]]"`

Comment: Regardless of what happens from here I am really thankful. If one of you want to post your comment as an answer I will of course recognize it as a correct answer.

Comment: `gsub("^\\D*?\\K(?=\\d+|/)|[^[:alnum:][:space:]]",",",string99, perl=TRUE)` gives `[1] "Foo ,35,10"     "Foo Bar ,7 , 0" "FooBar ,25 , 5" "I do ,156 , "`. How come you have a `/`? See [**this demo**](https://ideone.com/bKEyL3).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, it's almost there. I am doing a lot of trial of error here, but I added what you linked to to the question. There's a forward slash, `/`, in `"Foo  ,/10"`, I am currently trying to figure out how to substitute that for a `,`.

Comment: I think we are working from from different version of `string99`.

Comment: I suggest using `string` and `str_replace_all(string99, "^([^\\d/]*)|[^\\w\\s]", "\\1,")`

Comment: Works like a charm with using [tag:stringr]. Thanks a lot! If you post it as an answer I can mark it as answer. Thanks again!!

Comment: less clever again: `gsub('/|\\s{2,}|(?<=[a-z])(?=\\s+\\d)', ',', string99, perl = TRUE)`

Comment: It seems you may do the same with base R `gsub`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
string99 <- c("Foo  /10", "Foo Bar 7 / 0", "FooBar 25 / 5", "I do 156 / ")
gsub("^([^\\d/]*)|[^[:alnum:][:space:]]","\\1,",string99, perl=TRUE)
```

or

```
gsub("^([^\\d/]*)|[^\\w\\s]","\\1,",string99, perl=TRUE)
```

See the [R demo](https://ideone.com/1WQV05) and a [**regex demo**](https://regex101.com/r/jXgNjs/1).

**Pattern details**

- `^` - start of string
- `([^\\d/]*)` - Capturing group #1 (referenced to from the replacement pattern using the `\1` placeholder): any 0+ chars other than digit and `/`
- `|` - or
- `[^\\w\\s]` - any non-word and non-whitespace char.